# Robot Framework: Accessing methods in Python library subclasses

Tags: robotframework

I have a python file (example.py) containing a MainClass that is the interface to a test envrionment.
If tests are run via python they import MainClass, then accesses for example method_in_s1 via MainClass.s1.method_in_s1()

I also have some testcases that are run from robot, and I try to use the same approach and import MainClass and then accessing the subclass via MainClass.
However, I can not find a way to access the methods in the subclass from Robot FW. Is there a way to do this?

I have tried accessing the subclass in many different ways, here is a very short summary:

example.py:

```
class MainClass:

    def __init__(self):
        self.s1 = SubClass1()

    def method_in_main(self):
        print('MC')

class SubClass1:

    def __init__(self):
        self.dummy = 'dummy'

    def method_in_s1(self):
        print('S1')
```

ExampleRobot.robot:

```
*** Settings ***
Library    example.MainClass    WITH NAME    MC

*** Test Cases ***
Test1
    MC.method_in_main   # Works fine
    MC.s1.method_in_s1  # No keyword with name 'MC.s1.method_in_s1' found

Test2
    ${lib}=    Get Library Instance    MC
    ${lib}    method_in_main                           # Works fine
    Should Be Equal    ${lib.s1.dummy}    dummy        # Works fine
    ${lib.s1}    method_in_s1                          # No keyword with name 'method_in_s1' found.
```